# OO Design: Redundancy okay in showing "belongs to" relationship?

Tags: oop

If I have a class called Parent and it has Children stored in a list, then by storing the Children in this list, it is sufficient to establish that the Parent owns these Children and the children belong to the parent. But I feel more comfortable to also include a Parent field in the Child class definition. I think this may in fact be necessary for things like JPA; aside from this, is there a reason why this design choice is a good one? Or is it bad since it is not strictly necessary?

Comment: Java but would that have much bearing on the design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are referring to is the difference between a singly linked list or tree and a doubly linked list or tree. They are two distinct data structures and have their own uses.  Neither is better than the other, each is "correct" for the situation in which it is needed.

In other words, you shouldn't use a doubly linked structure for a situation that only requires a singly linked structure and vice versa.

A singly linked structure tends to use less memory and requires less work to update, and if you only traverse it one way then there is no need for a doubly linked structure.  However, if you intend to traverse both ways, it can be faster to use a doubly linked structure.

Comment: I am thinking of an ArrayList of children. The ArrayList is a field in Parent. Each Child could have a Parent field or not. I am asking, apart from the requirements of JPA or other persistence approaches, whether having a Parent field in Child is good practice. There are no linked lists involved here as far as I understand your response.

Comment: @Jeff - If you have a parent and child you have a linked list (whether it be a tree or a list). An array is sequential, a linked list uses pointers or references.  And my response is quite clear, there is no "good idea" or not.  There is only whether the situation requires two way traversal or not, if it does, then you need the parent field, if it doesn't then you don't.

Comment: Thanks Erik. I think then the answer is if you never refer to the Children in a context outside of the Parent's list field, there is no need for the Parent field, right?

Answer (score 0):

First off, I assume this applies to some generic OO language such as Java. I don't know if there is a one-size-fits-all answer to this question as it will depend on whether having that additional association is actually going to be helpful. If you are always referencing child objects via the Parent, such as `parentObj.getChildren().get(1)` then I don't see why it's necessary. It's just one additional thing to remember to update/account for that could possibly get out of synch.

There may of course be some situations where by nature of how you are accessing things, it is entirely acceptable to have this parent attribute in the Child class.

OOD/A is tricky in this way—we don't want to create too many associations as this results in tight coupling and code that breaks easily, but we don't want to avoid associations altogether as this would defeat much of the utility of OOP.

Answer (score 0):

two choices are good. Sometimes when you need to write a Core or Business Layer, some kind of task, requires you have reference on both sides, but in other ways you only need one. I suggest you to thinking on what are your business requirements and choose an option to fill your meets.

Another tip to get on mind is: some ORMs libs maybe forces you to use reference on both sides, specially if you use your business entities en core and dataa access layers.